# InputBox Cancel

Tags: vb6

I have created an Inputbox to get the username entered but stuck with the cancel button

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
fsUserName = UCase(InputBox("Please Enter your name.", "User Name", _
"dc"))

If fsUserName = "" Then
MsgBox "No name Entered." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & _
"You must enter a name.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
Form_Load
ElseIf VarType(fsUserName) = 0 Then 'If cancel clicked
cmdQuit_Click

End If
```

Also is there a way that when the X button on the form is clicked it executes cmdQuit_Click so that if the userclicks the command button Quit or X ,the Quit script is run.In the quit script there are message boxes and cleanup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `StrPtr()` to detect if cancel was clicked;

```
Dim fsUserName As String

fsUserName = InputBox("Please Enter your name.", "User Name", "dc")

If (StrPtr(fsUserName) = 0&) Then
    MsgBox "Cancelled or X clicked"
ElseIf fsUserName = "" Then
    MsgBox "No name Entered." & vbCr & "You must enter a name.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
Else
    fsUserName = UCase$(fsUserName)
    MsgBox fsUserName
End If
```

If you want to do something when the form unloads you can use the `Form_Unload` event or better the `Form_QueryUnload` event which fires before the actual unload & allows you to cancel it.
It will also tell you why the form is unloading (`UnloadMode` will be 0 if the red X is clicked)

Using "`Unload Me`" will raise both of the events.

**Edit:** Calling `Form_Load` in `Form_Load` like that will eventually fill up the stack, better to use a loop to look for a missing username.

Comment: Thanks Alex,the solution worked perfect for me.I would be glad if you could guide me the Loop part also.Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Alex's answer using StrPtr, which I assume works as advertised, is good as far as it goes, but the better advice (IMO) is to avoid InputBox altogether. You can easily create your own using a dialog-style form, a textbox, and a couple of buttons, and maybe an icon if you like.

Rolling your own gives you complete flexibility and predictability, and once you have it you can use it in any future projects.

Comment: VB6's InputBox() function is a very thin wrapper on the equivalent API call, which documents Cancel as returning a null pointer.  In the rare case where an InputBox is useful that detection technique is fine - there is no reliability issue.  However I agree InputBox() is a poor choice for production programs the average user will interact with.

Comment: It was very nice of Jim to suggest that creating my own custom dialog box is far better than using inputbox.The dialog box can be given a much more professional look.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Excel `InputBox` and `Application.InputBox` are different functions.

```
Sub GetValue2()
    Dim Monthly As Variant
    Monthly = Application.InputBox _
        (Prompt:="Podaj wysokość miesięcznej wypłaty:", _
         Type:=1)
    If Monthly = False Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox "Zarobki rocznie: " & Monthly * 12
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Name = Application.InputBox("Please enter Name")

If Name = "False" Then

MsgBox " Your message here"

Exit Sub

End If