# InputBox Cancel using C++

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am using the InputBox component in Embarcadero or Borland C++ with a default string.  The Cancel key returns the same default string as the Enter button.

According to the documentation, the Cancel key is supposed to return an empty string.

```
String s = InputBox("Title", "Prompt", "Default");
if (s == "") return;  // Cancel key pressed
... use string s
```

I have seen a solution using StrPtr in VB.  Is there an equivalent in C++?
[VB6 InputBox Cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123679/inputbox-cancel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution that uses InputQuery instead of InputBox. The InputQuery functions returns FALSE if the Cancel button is selected.  The DefaultString is returned on Enter.

Comment: This is mentioned in the `InputBox()` documentation: "*If the application needs to know whether the user chooses OK or Cancel, use the InputQuery function instead.*"

Answer (score 2):

Per the [InputBox documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Dialogs.InputBox):

> If the user chooses the Cancel button, InputBox returns the default
>   value.

So, basically you can just make default string empty and it will be returned with the Cancel.